# HTTParty Ruby Authentication

Tags: ruby, authentication

How would I convert:

```
curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: token sampleToken" https://api.github.com/repos/sampleUser/deletedRepos
```

into a command for HTTParty? I'm having trouble dealing with the header. I think the way I input the header currently doesn't work. Here's what I'm trying right now:

```
  HTTParty.delete("https://api.github.com/repos/sampleUser/deletedRepos/", header: "Authorization: token sampleToken")
```

Comment: AFAIK, the option is `headers:` and expects a hash argument.

Comment: What @orde said is correct. Try as HTTParty.delete("https://api.github.com/repos/sampleUser/deletedRepos/", headers: { "Authorization" => "token sampleToken" })

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work. I'm sure the token works. Thanks for the suggestions, would you happen to have any other ideas?